# A Java SE app to be moved to a Java EE Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1

I have a Java SE application that runs in its own JVM using java -jar. It has a main function that registers some callbacks for certain SMPP servers and the main thread after registering those call backs keeps on checking the connectivity for those servers.

Can this kind of an app be moved to a Java EE server like the WebSphere application server?

What would be the architectural changes?

Above is a single threaded console application that runs untill its process is killed. It keeps on checking the connectivity.

Comment: Is the app listening to some ports?

Comment: yes,it registers some listeners using jsmpp.

Answer (score 1):

*Can this kind of an app be moved to a Java EE server like the WebSphere application server?*

Yes, technicall any application logic can run inside an application server, it is just a matter of how you package the app, and which descriptors you apply. Depending on that you may have to implement a few interfaces which serve as callback methods or listeners for the server to start and shutdown your app.

A good reason to let an application run inside an application server is probably that in a heavily standardized and managed environment a service provider would only offer non-standardized services or products for a **lot** of extra money.

Another good reason is that you want to use managed resources from the application server. This can be messaging or persistence for instance.

In any case you need to understand both the costs and the benefits of using an application server.

*What would be the architectural changes?*

You would have to have the container (applications server) manage the lifecycle of your app through interfaces or listeners. For instance if you decide to package your application as a WebApp (don't know if that's a good thing in your case, there are other options), then you probably will have to implement a Filter or a ContextListener and declare all that in an xml descriptor (web.xml).

What you also could do is to change your application to use the Spring container, and then let the application server fire up Spring which will then run your Application.

This would offer you the opportunity to be able to still run/test your app without an application server if you need to, and at the same time be able to use its resources at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the HTTP services of a web container (such as Servlets, JSPs, JSF) nor the many services of an Application Server (such as EJBs or JMS etc.), then there may be no reason to update this application to a Java EE Server.  You didn't specify the motivation for doing so.

Placing the application in a web container like Tomcat or an application server like WebSphere may give you enhanced manageability but at a significant cost.

An alternative is to use a JavaService wrapper such as defined by Mike Jennings' DDJ article in March 2000.  I have used this approach; then added the functionality I needed, piecemeal.  Commercial versions of this sort of approach are available (such as Tanuki Software).  This can make for a very lightweight approach so long as you don't end up needing Java EE-type services.

Comment: The only motivation we have is managed shutdown of the app,avoid any abnormal process termination from external world and a container like an app server to hold the app in its JVM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do this other than stupid management edicts. Resist such edicts.

Answer (score 0):

Having a whole application server just to run a single jar is like to employ a racing car maintaining team for your 1980s Volkswagen. It would just be overkill. If you don't need any features from the application server for your jar, why would you think about using it in the first place?

Applicationserver have certain features but also require more knowledge and resources to set up and maintain. Using one for the sake of using an applicationserver isn't always the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Swing screens will be converted to JSP's
2. Logic will run in server getting data from JSP pages.
3. You can use Spring MVC framework.

Comment: current application is a console based java app, and when moved to an app server it has to start on its own without any interaction from UI end. And probably it doesn't need any UI for the tasks its already doing.